# Modal not popping up in bootstrap.When I clicked "Learn more" modal is not opening up ?Can someone tell me where i went wrong

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have provided the code below and Plunkr link as well.Modal doesn't display properly when I click the "Learn more" button the issue araises.Can someone tell me where exactly I went wrong.The details are provided below.Well, how about adding more details. Like, what are you trying to accomplish, how are you doing it, what difficulties you have found with the approach, another approaches you have tried, etc. In summary, without code isn't a good question neither is with just code. Search for the balance!

code: http://plnkr.co/edit/X8ReWNKXK9RLVvrzeTd5?p=info

```
 <body ng-app="myApp">
 <div class="container">
 <div ng-controller="listCtrl">
 <div class="well">
 <h1>Welcome to ssrikanthpp</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="x in data">
 <div class="well well-sm">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <img ng-src="{{x.image_url}}" 
 class="img-rounded img-responsive well-image">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <h4>{{x.type}}</h4>
 <p><strong>Locations: </strong>{{x.locations}}</p>
 <p><strong>Size: </strong>{{x.size}}</p>
 <p><strong>Average Lifespan: </strong>{{x.lifespan}}</p>
 <p><strong>Diet: </strong>{{x.diet}}</p>
 <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="model" target="#turtle-info">Learn more..</button> 
 </div>
 </div>
 <!-- row -->
 </div>
 <!-- well -->
 </div>
 <!-- col-xs-6 -->
 </div>
 <!-- model starts hre -->
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div id="turtle-info" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <!-- Modal content-->
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
 <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <!-- model ends here -->
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't realy an answer but I can't post a comment because I just started ad SO.

Just rename target to data-target. That should solve the problem.

Comment: And you've data-toggle="model". Rename model to modal

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

change this line 
`<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="model" target="#turtle-info">Learn more..</button>` 
to
 `<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="modal" target="#turtle-info">Learn more..</button>` 
and you should be good to go